# How can I add colums to magento 1.9.2.3 Nav menu?

Tags: magento-1.9, topmenu

I currently have:

```
Shoes
[ ALL ]
[Men's ]
[Ladies]
```

It's pretty basic and standard. I also have brands [hidden from menu] - things like `/shoes/nike.html` etc.

I want to add a column to the top menu to hold links to brands. I have played with html/css using divs to hold the columns. How do I translate this over to magento or can you think of a better way to achieve this?!

Answer (score 0):

One thing you can do, is to add new product attribute (brand) with options Nike,Adidas,... and then create custom menu which will be linked etc /brands.html?brands=nike or something like that (Uses core filter functionality)... It is just one solution, that you can think about it... With this kind of solution you can achieve that it will take all assigned products from categoriy which have only brand nike or etc.

Comment: Thanks for your input. I've though about this and of course it's all in place already. However, I feel it is better from a SEO / user experience having the menu link to page(s). If I can't figure it out then I'll try your method out :)

Answer (score 0):

Small update. I searched through Github and came across this plugin: https://github.com/magazento/Magazento_Megamenu

Can't get it to replace the main nav menu but it looks like what i'm after. How can I override the main nav menu?